# modify android xml template elements in a website

Tags: android, angularjs, xml, templates

I have a question regarding Android XML templates and Website programming.

I have several android template files (XML files). I have a website that shows all the different android templates available. I was wondering if its possible for a user, using the website, to choose a template and be able to modify the elements in the template? for example: say he wants to add an image in an imageview in the provided template, or resize a textview, or change the background colour/image of the android template etc? and the template should be able to save any changes to the xml so that the modified xml can be used for android dev. This is just an idea and I wanted to know if it would be feasible.

I am quite new to android development but i do know web dev using HTML, JS and angularJS. Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this website is not going to know any of the android specific elements so no. just use android studio

Comment: so you're saying its impossible to edit android templates via website? if its not possible to edit a pre created template. would be it be possible to create an xml file through a website?

Comment: you can edit what you want in the end its just a xml file but if you make a mistake with some attribute the website isnt going to know its an error like android studio will

Comment: its possible although quite complex - you must be proficient in android to understand all the stuff going on and optimise your site to make efficient xml that can be added in the android project.

Comment: By editing xml file what exactly do you mean? the xml file is going to be an android format one. so is it like changing the code in the xml? or can a user visually edit an android xml?

Comment: @Shubhank what if my website doesnt need to create an android xml from scratch but edit an already provided one? like the question i asked earlier, if its possible to edit an android xml via a website, could a user visually edit it? like resize an imageview or do they have to manually change the xml code?

Comment: visually modifying things itself does not work well on the IDE so making it functional is definitely a no go for the website. altering the xml in website also won't give autocomplete for the attributes which makes it useless. Only thing worth in this approach is that you expose some common functionality for non technical users. If you dont want that - i would say just stick to the studio

Comment: @Shubhank Thanks for that. On another note, what if i have a placeholder xml created in android studio. and if i give the user to provide configuration values (like choose background colour, textview size etc) where these values can be stored in the database, can we then use these values from the DB to somehow add them to our xml file ? (just a thought, excuse me if it doesnt make sense)